# RXJS Observables how to access multiple observable values from mergeMap

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-observables

I have an rxjs function using several rxjs operators from which I need to ultimately return an observable.  My challenge is detailed below in the sample code with details of what I am trying to do.  How can I accomplish this?  Do I need a rewrite?  Without the change I'm trying to make to access the values from Observable3 everything works as needed.  I've tried many things including using `withLatestFrom` to bring in observable three and also `combineLatest` but to no luck.

```
Observable3 = of({obs3Prop1: value1, obs3Prop2: value2})

    this.Observable1
        .pipe(
            switchMap(param1) => {
                return this.getCount(param1);
            }), 
            mergeMap((param2: number) => 
                this.Observable2
                .pipe(
                    //inside this pipe, return another observable from here using some rxjs operators
                    //where I need access to param2 
                    //but I also need access to the value from Observable3
                )
            ),
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you could use just `forkJoin()` assuming the all source Observables complete:

```
mergeMap((param2: number) => 
  forkJoin([
    Observable3,
    this.Observable2,
  ]).pipe(
    mergeMap(([o3params, o2params]) => this.makeCall(o3params.param1, o2params)),
  )
),
```

Comment: Will try that, but inside that last pipe, do I have access to param2?  That is where I was getting hung up.  In that last pipe I would need to be able to access param2 AND Observable2 AND Observable3.  I slightly clarified in the question.  Initially I had said I already had access to param2, but that was based on the existing setup.

Comment: You have because `param2` is in the same closure as the last pipe.

Comment: Ok. I will give it a try.